# the status bar is showing html instead of php

Tags: sublimetext2

in sublimetext2 make a new php file with the below code

```
<?php


function copy_taxonomy_menu() {
$items = array();

$items['admin/content/taxonomy/copy_question'] = array(
'title' => t('Copy Question'),
'access callback' =>'user_access',
'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form,'
'page arguments' => array('copy_taxonomy_page'),
'description' => t('Copy taxonomy from one content to another '),
'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
?>
```

the syntax is selected as php but the status bar at the bottom still shows html. What is wrong here ?

Comment: It could just be a display bug in the editor. Clicking on `HTML` brings up  a list of languages, and `PHP` is selected. Additionally, a quick scope check shows that the syntax being applied to the entire file is HTML. The PHP is listed as an embedded scope. Unless it's breaking some functionality for you, I'd just ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to `Preferences > Browse Packages... > HTML` and open `HTML.tmLanguage`, you can see this line:

```xml
<key>firstLineMatch</key>
<string>&lt;!(?i:DOCTYPE)|&lt;(?i:html)|&lt;\?(?i:php)</string>
```

This means that if your file starts with (case insensitive) `<!doctype`, `<html` or `<?php`, the syntax will be defined as HTML. If this is a problem for you, you can edit the `<string>` to the above:

```xml
<key>firstLineMatch</key>
<string>&lt;!(?i:DOCTYPE)|&lt;(?i:html)</string>
```

Comment: Try to close the file, close and reopen Sublime Text to reload your plugins and packages. Then reopen the file to test. I did this test here and the syntax changed to PHP. If you got the HTML5 package installed, maybe you need to do the same with `HTML5.tmLanguage` file.